# My Azure Machine Learning Web Service has same result.How to overcome this problem?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-webapps

My project is binary classification prediction.I make standardise my numeric values and apply one-hot encoding to categorical values.I trained data and get 80% accuracy.I want to create web service and it has original data input and original data output but currently score model has standardised and one-hot encoded datas.So I concat two table which are original data and my prediction table's score probability,Scored label columns.Then I linked to web service output.I created web service but when I change feature datas Web service output always has same result.Where is my fault? At below,you can see my model.
[image: My model]

Answer (score 0):

How are you verifying that the output is the same? By making an API call, right?

My understanding is that's the only way to use the web service output.

Comment: When you deploy web service in Azure Machine Learning Studio, you can test your new data with Request-Response tab and when you change your data, your prediction should change according to your input data.But when I change my input data,it doesn't change.